# User permissions jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an intranet site that has to display/block content for users based on their entitlements. I retrieve the entitlements based on their ID from the database and store it in  tags hidden on the site. Originally, it was just 1 dimensional, so I created a bunch of tags like so to track their entitlements.

```
<div id="USA" access="Read">
<div id="CANADA" access="Write">
```

As they navigate around the site, I would check against these tags to either allow or deny access. Later on, I had to expand it so it became like so:

```
<div id="USA" state="New York, New Jersey, Connecticut" access="Read">
<div id="CANADA" state="Ontario, Quebec" access="Write">
```

That resulted in a limitation that I couldn't give both read and write access to one person in a specific country, but that wasn't an issue at the time. Now, I need to add a third layer to it but I'm not sure how to do it.

The new design would also need to overcome the limitation of the previous design so that users will have read access in X cities, but write access in Y cities. This is what I was thinking but I don't think it will work again:

```
<div country="" state="" city="" access="" >
```

Is there an elegant way to create div tags or another way to store/retrieve user entitlements easily?

Comment: (As a side note,) You know anyone can just change those attributes client-side, right? My point being, is there a server-side check as well?

Comment: add a server side authentication/login system. Right now, all the data is accessible by anyone able to press F12 on their keyboard

Comment: Also, if you are going to use your own custom attributes then you should make them data-attributes (with the `data-` prefix) so that your HTML is still valid.

Comment: There is server side authentication when they log in via the intranet. The page then displays all surveys available. This code is used to limit what surveys they can load based on their job role.

Comment: @JimC Did you even read my comment? Let's say I'm a user who can login, but has only read access to everything. Now I open up the browser console and type `document.getElementById("USA").setAttribute("access", "Write")`. Now I can write what you think I can't. What are you doing about this?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery (or any client side code for that matter) should not be the primary method used to implement security restrictions in a web site. The client side is easily hackable/modifiable so you will want to implement a server side security method. For example, only add input fields to your page if the logged in user is a member of the appropriate group.